# How to delete UITextfield and entered data from it in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have develop one application and in that I have two `UIButton` named [+] and [-] and one `UITextField` default.

Now what I want is when I click on plus *[+]* button it should add one `UITextField` in `UIView` that is work perfectly to me but when I click on minus [-] button it should delete last created UITextField that is not working now for me.

How to manage that?

here is my code to plus[+] button.

```
- (IBAction)btnPlusClicked:(id)sender
{

    scrollViewSpecialitiesTxtFields.hidden = FALSE;

    float y;

    y = (35 * txtSpecialityFieldCounter);

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 120, 30)];
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

    [arraySpecialitiesTxtFields insertObject:textField atIndex:arraySpecialitiesTxtFields.count];

    scrollViewSpecialitiesTxtFields.contentSize = CGSizeMake(125, y+30);
    [scrollViewSpecialitiesTxtFields addSubview:textField];

    txtSpecialityFieldCounter++;
    NSLog(@"txtSpecialityFieldCounter : %d",txtSpecialityFieldCounter);
}
```

here is my minus [-] button code

```
-(IBAction)btnMinusClicked:(id)sender
{
    [scrollViewSpecialitiesTxtFields.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    txtSpecialityFieldCounter--;
    NSLog(@"txtSpecialityFieldCounter : %d",txtSpecialityFieldCounter);

    float y;

    y = (35 * txtSpecialityFieldCounter);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < txtSpecialityFieldCounter; i++)
    {
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 120, 30)];
        textField.delegate = self;
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

        [arraySpecialitiesTxtFields insertObject:textField atIndex:arraySpecialitiesTxtFields.count];

        scrollViewSpecialitiesTxtFields.contentSize = CGSizeMake(125, y-30);
        [scrollViewSpecialitiesTxtFields addSubview:textField];
    }
}
```

I know minus[-] button code is wrong but let me know changes

Comment: show your delete IBAction

Comment: also, your textfield is local to only that IBAction method, and won't be retained when you click the plus button again, is this what you wanted?

Comment: sorry for that. wait a minute i update my whole code and also let you know what i actually want.

Comment: No problem, I think you may already have an answer below this

Comment: Tejas, how many textfiels should I be albe to add? Shoudl I be able to add as many as I want to add?

Comment: So, if I want to add 100 text fields I could and then delete 100 textfields? HYpothetically?

Comment: you can add maximum 10 UITextField by clicking [+]. once you click [+] it should add one UITextField and maximum number is 10 then it should give validation ("you can not add more text"). something like that

Comment: yep, one sec, I'll have a ful answer for you

Comment: yes please send me full answer @Larcerax

Answer (score 1):

Create a global variable as `NSMutableArray *myAddedTextfields` and in `viewDidLoad-> myAddedTextFields = [NSMutableArray array];`

```
- (IBAction)plusAction:(id)sender 
{
UITextField *textField1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 20)];

textField1.text = @"hey how r u";

textField1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

textField1.tag = 1;
[self.view addSubview:textField1];
[myAddedTextFields addObject:textField1];
}

- (IBAction)minusAction:(id)sender 
{
UITextField *txtField = [myAddedTextFields objectAtIndex:myAddedTextFields.count -1]; //for deleting from the last textfield onwards.

[txtField removeFromSuperView];
[myAddedTextFields removeObjectIdenticalTo:txtField];

}
```

I have edited your method.. hope this helps.

Comment: thanks bro. this is working but still it is delete my first UITextField and then next and continued.

Comment: Which one do you want to delete?

Comment: wait i give you one example. when you add someone contact number in you phone, and if you want to add one more number then you have to click on plus button and if don't want to add another contact then you have to click on [-] button and it will remove extra created number field right.  i want to implement same functionality in my app.

Comment: I'll leet Saheb continue answering this one, but what you can do is start with a global counter of like 87982, jsut a random integer, when a text field is added, then add this counter +1 as the tag

Comment: then, with the number stored as a static variable as well, subtract the counter at the end of the + and when the minus starts and then begin removing the tags from the correct order. I say use a random number so that there are no clashes with other processes using the taggin system

Comment: I changed the edit to a more specific and thorough way by adding it in an array and then managing the array for deletion

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to add an `UITextField` on a superview, set the tag of that component (UITextField).

And when you want to remove it from superview then get the reference of that component (`UITextField`) using the tag and remove it from the superview.

Here is an example that may be helpful to you:

```
-(IBAction)plusAction:(id)sender 
{
    UITextField *textField1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 20)];

    textField1.text = @"hey how r u";

    textField1.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    textField1.tag = 1;
    [self.view addSubview:textField1];
}

-(IBAction)minusAction:(id)sender 
{
    UITextField * textfield = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
    [textfield removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: i tried this one as well. and this is also works for me. Thanks.

Comment: I am not the person who answered the question :) I fixed one letter :)

Comment: please, upvote the corrent answers to show appreciation for the ppl who answered :)

Comment: hasan83 . ya i know . thanks to kavita for answer my question and also thanks to you for modification :):)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use the tag option. Or you could use an `NSArray` holding your `UITextFields`.

```
@interface MyTextFieldViewClass ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *textFields;

@end

@implementation MyTextFieldViewClass

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textFields = [NSMutableArray array];
}

- (IBAction)addTextField:(id)sender {
    UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 20)];

    [self.textFields addObject:tf];
    [self.view addSubview:tf];
}

- (IBAction)removeTextField:(id)sender {
    UITextField *tf = [self.textFields lastObject];
    [tf removeFromSuperview];

    [self.textFields removeLastObject];
}

@end
```

This would be a little better since you do not have to iterate over all the views/ids that exist in self.view.subviews. Also, using the `tag` might not be reliable since you always want to remove the last item, so you would either need to keep the last item number in memory or you need to iterate over all the subviews in order to find the `UITextField` with the highest tag and in order to remove it.

Comment: This is really simple solution you gave me. thanks @Paul Peelen.. works for me too

Comment: Sure thing. Glad I could help. Keep in mind though, I haven't tested my code.. its written directly here on SO.

Comment: ya good, have some modification done by my side but this is work for me. thanks a lot